# Android: Disable HorizontalScrollView end of scrolling edge

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview, custom-scrolling

I mean that i want to get rid of the "end of scrolling indicator" that appears when the user try to overscroll the view:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

never mind, i've found a neat feature called android:overScrollMode="never".

that did the trick :D